# How to change another activity field text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I want to change the login/password EditText with the login/password values of register activity.

The issue is that the EditText is not created in the register activity, giving a null error reference it (obviously because the activity is different from the current - register cannot access the login xml components)

> Process: com.guincho7.customer, PID: 14877
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

The activity hierarchy is:

*Login - new intent(NOT FINISH) -> Register - Sucessful Register -> Finish register activity (back to Login activity that was on foreground)*

How can I do this with the best implementation possible?

Comment: See this link this question is already have answer it is duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088394/extra-from-activity-b-to-activity-a

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` in your `LoginActivity`.
For example in your `LoginActivity` use this:

```
static final int REGISTER_REQUEST = 1; // The request code.
private void register() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REGISTER_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REGISTER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String login = data.getStringExtra("login");
            loginEditText.setText(login);
            String pass = data.getStringExtra("pass");
            passEditText.setText(pass);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `RegisterActivity` set the data before finish like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("login", loginEditText.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("pass", passEditText.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```